# Video "Analysis" Software

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

Is there any software that can run on Ubuntu that has video "analyzing" capabilities?

I have a video from my security camera and would like to zoom in. I have tried OpenShot but it doesn't really do the job right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are saying then you need an application that enable you to zoom a video?!

For that you can use the amazing application `VLC`, install it if you didn't yet:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Now to enable zooming:

- run your video using VLC
- Click on the Tools menu > Effects and Filters.

[image]

- Click on the Video Effects menu > Geometry.
- Check "Interactive Zoom"

[image]

- The VLC zoom option is enabled.
- Move the rectangular selection tool to select the area you want to
  zoom.
- From there simply adjust the zoom level.

[image]

Comment: VLC can do this!?! Well it's always good to learn something new everyday :) I been using VLC for years and I didn't know it can do this. It's so funny though, I watched the video in VLC too. I appreciate it mate, you inspired me to read the VLC documentation.